Failed to encode Unicode object to locale Abaqus Error: Abaqus/CAE GUI exited with an error
enter image description here
When starting ABAQUS/CAE, the above error occurs. How can it be resolved? Thank you！
Abaqus License Manager checked out the following license:
"cae" from Flexnet server localhost
<9998 out of 9999 licenses remain available>.
Failed to encode Unicode object to locale
Abaqus Error: Abaqus/CAE GUI exited with an error.
请按任意键继续. . .

I am not entirely sure, but, I believe, this could be Abaqus installation issue. I think, you have Chinese language in your system, and may be Abaqus installation is not with the same language. Have you selected the correct language while installing the Abaqus?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Just had the same problem. The mistake that i made, was to name my part with the letter "Ü". Using letters that are used in english fixed the problem for me.
